# Specifying different output directory for target will not work

Tags: makefile

```
SOURCE := ../Src/Folder1/source.a66
OBJ := ../Src/Folder1/source._ia
OUT := ../Obj

all: $(OBJ)
    echo "DONE"

# 1) Works    
%._ia: %.a66
    echo "Test" > $@
# 2) Don't work
$(OUT)/%._ia: %.a66
    echo "Test" > $@
```

- When I use the first target, the file is created in `../Src/Folder1`
- When I use the second target, when running make I get :

> `make: *** No rule to make target '../Src/Folder1/Os_cpu_a._ia', needed by '../Obj/target'.  Stop.`
>   
>   What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least you have to modify prerequisites of `all` (value of `$(OBJ)`):

```
OBJ := ../Obj/Folder1/source._ia
```

Then modify your pattern rule as follows:

```
../Obj/%._ia: ../Src/%.a66
    echo "Test" > $@
```

Finally, after extracting `../Obj` and `../Src` to variables, you'll get something like:

```
SRC_DIR := ../Src
OBJ_DIR := ../Obj

SRC := $(SRC_DIR)/Folder1/source.a66
OBJ := $(SRC:$(SRC_DIR)/%.a66=$(OBJ_DIR)/%._ia)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%._ia: $(SRC_DIR)/%.a66
    echo "Test" > $@
```